# Chrome 72 Blocks XHR in Extension's Content Script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cross-origin-read-blocking

After update Chrome to version 72, my extension doesn't work any more. It used to work on version 71.
My extension sends a request to get some data within the same website.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/gym/combo/incident?id=" + incidentId + "&lockerEntity=widget_group", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But Chrome blocked the response because of Cross-Origin Read Blocking. The warning message is like:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://example.com/gym/combo/incident?id=6418e9fc-9176-4c82-b6ea-455551a9b53e&lockerEntity=widget_group with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details
```

I don't understand why it's Cross-Origin when the script make the request to the same site. Could this be a bug?

Comment: It might be a bug but anyway you can do the request in your background page script and send the results back via messaging.

Comment: It's fixed in Chrome 73 (a week or two until its release), see https://crbug.com/918660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to wOxxOm. It turns out to be a bug. [crbug.com/918660](http://crbug.com/918660)